# while loop does not preform else statement and repeat loop

Tags: java, while-loop

When compiled upon not entering the right selection it doesnt display to re-enter or repeat the loop

```
int counterA = 0;
while (counterA < 0) {
    if (conversionSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("binary"))
            counterA++;
    if (conversionSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("octal"))
            counterA++;
    else System.out.println("Error. Please enter weither to convert the Hex to Octal or Binary:");
        conversionSelection = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop should not execute at all since the condition fails right from the get-go.

There is also a dangling else statement. So you need to have an else-if for your second if statement if you want the else to properly execute. While it may not currently produce errors, it is an important skill to prevent dangling 'else's'.

Comment: Thank you... and I originally wrote the code to have the else if statement but kept writing it as "if else" and couldnt figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never enter the `while` loop since `counterA = 0` and the while loop condition is for it to be `< 0`. You want `counterA` to be less than zero, or the condition to include `counterA`'s value in its set (e.g. `while (counterA <= 0)`).

Answer (score 0):

This loop will never start because 0 is not smaller than 0.